# Don't prompt for which email address when sending message from Watch

Tags: apple-watch

When I use my Apple Watch to send a text message to my wife, it first prompts me to ask which email address to use. (Oddly, it does not include her phone number as an option).

Is there a way I can configure the watch to always use a certain email address?

For now, I've just removed her other email addresses from her contacts and put them in the notes field instead as a workaround.

Comment: Are you both using Apple devices or is your wife on Android?

Comment: @fsb We are both using Apple devices.

Comment: Are you following [these steps from Apple](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT205783) on starting a message?  I'm just trying to figure out where the problem is happening.

Comment: @fsb I'm using voice. Specifically, I hold in the crown and say (for example), "Send a message to my wife: I am going to be late".

Comment: That's strange because I do the exact same thing with my Watch and it always users her iPhone number (I don't send messages to her email address).  Does your wife have multiple phone numbers on her contact?